# Mastermind: Evaluating the guess

Tags: python, algorithm, python-3.x, functional-programming

The `evaluate_guess` function below returns the evaluation of a guess with respect to Mastermind [game rules](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mastermind_(board_game)):

```
# sample secret code and guess
secret_code = ["a", "a", "c", "a"]
guess = ["c", "a", "a", "b"]


def evaluate_guess(secret_code, guess):
    score = []
    temp_list = secret_code.copy()

    for i in range(len(secret_code)):
        if guess[i] == temp_list[i]:
            score.append(1)
            temp_list[i] = None

        elif guess[i] in temp_list:
            score.append(0)
            temp_list[temp_list.index(guess[i])] = None

    score.sort(reverse=True)
    return score

print(evaluate_guess(secret_code, guess))

>>> [1, 0, 0]
```

1. Without changing the essence of the algorithm: Can I implement the `evaluate_guess` function in a more Pythonic way? Is it possible to implement the algorithm in a purely functional fashion?
2. Is there a more straightforward algorithm?

Comment: This isn't functional-programming, it's imperative.

Comment: I have rolled back the last edit. Please see *[What to do when someone answers](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers)*.

Comment: Hello there, I rolled back the latest edit. I strongly recommend you read the link provided by TheCoffeeCup in the previous comment, since that explains why they rolled back and also why I rolled back. Please don't edit your question in that way. If you have further questions, feel free to drop by in [chat]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Most of the solutions provided so far is hard to read, and you need to really think before you understand what is happening, so I would like to propose an alternative approach as a response to a more straightforward algorithm:

```
def evaluate_guess(secret_code, guesses):

    score = []
    remaining_secrets = []
    remaining_guesses = []

    # Check exact matches
    for guess, secret in zip(secret_code, guesses):
        if guess == secret:
            score.append(1)

        else:
            remaining_guesses.append(guess)
            remaining_secrets.append(secret)

    # Check wrong placing
    for guess in remaining_guesses:

        if guess in remaining_secrets:
            score.append(0)
            remaining_secrets.remove(guess)

    return score
```

The only magic in this code is the joining of `secret_code` and `guesses` using `zip` which joins them index for index. This allows for, in my opinion, code that is easier to understand instead of list comprehensions, ifilters, index searching, sorting, sliceing and other stuff.

Comment: Yes, your code is both straightforward and easy to read.

Answer (score 3):

If this were functional programming, then `temp_list[i] = None` should never happen.

And so, you would be able to do:

```
# Ugly Python functional programming.
return list(sorted(map(
    lambda i: guess[i] == secret_code[i]
    filter(lambda i: guess[i] in secret_code, range(len(guess)))
)), reverse=True))
```

Or using a comprehension:

```
return list(sorted((
    guess[i] == secret_code[i]
    for i in range(len(guess))
    if guess[i] in secret_code
), reverse=True))
```

---

## But it is not.

Your algorithm is actually really good.

The best way to make it more Pythonic, is to use `enumerate`.
That way, you are both generating `i`, and indexing `guess` at the same time.

Also, you have a bug. This is as you remove some future used items with your `temp_list` that uses `index`. For an example if you input `['a', 'b', 'a'], ['a', 'a', 'a']`, you get `[1, 0]` not `[1, 1]`.

```
def evaluate_guess(secret_code, guess):
    secret_code = secret_code.copy()
    ones = [
        1
        for secret, guess_item in zip(secret_code, guess)
        if secret == guess_item 
    ]

    zeros = []
    for guess_item in guess:
        if guess_item in secret_code:
            secret_code[secret_code.index(guess_item)] = None
            zeros.append(0)

    return ones + zeros[:-len(ones)]

evaluate_guess(["a", "a", "c", "a"], ["c", "a", "a", "b"])
#[1, 0, 0]
```

**Note**: this algorithm is \$O(n^2)\$ and so you may want to change it to a more \$O(n)\$ algorithm if you need to support larger numbers.

Comment: Excellent catch. Changed my unpythonic code accordingly.

Comment: I appreciate the contrast between the paradigms. I think it's important to outline that different languages work differently and encourage different practices.

Answer (score 1):

A more pythonic way to do this would be to use list comprehensions:

```
def evaluate_guess(secret_code, guess):
    score1 = [1 for i in range(len(secret_code)) if guess[i] == secret_code[i]]  ## list for exact matches
    score2 = [0 for i in range(len(secret_code)) if guess[i] in secret_code]   ## list for "color" matches
    score1.extend(score2[:-len(score1)])
    score1.sort(reverse=True)  
    ## in this method, every 1 also shows up as a zero, so when you combine the lists, you just account for that by subtracting a zero for every one that appears
    return score1
```

It's up to you whether this is more "straightforward".  Some people like list comprehensions, and for others (like me) I find them a little harder to read because I'm still not that used to them.

In this version, you don't need to keep up with the temp_list, and you also don't need the step of initializing the lists, because they are created in a single step.  (so, fewer lines of code)

Comment: I suspect your algorithm is erroneous, especially `score2 = [0 for i in range(len(code)) if guess[i] in code]`.

Comment: I did find a bug where I mixed in some Java...need to do the sort on a separate line.  When I run this code with your inputs, I get your desired output.

Comment: @blackened - I tried more test cases, including all correct, and none correct, and it works.  Are you having a problem with it?

Comment: Why using `i in range(len(code)) `? For 1 you can use `for c,g in zip(secret_code, guess) if c == g` and for 0 `for g in guess if g in secret_code`. Besides `len(code)` is a `NameError`.

Comment: After reading this again (and not being half asleep) I think this is the best solution, +1.
I think you should add more of a review of OP's code and explain the algorithm a little.
E.g. for every `guess[i] == secret_code[i]`, `guess[i] in secret_code` is true.
\$\therefore \text{score1} \subset \text{score2}\$ and so `score2[:-len(score1)]` removes the duplicates.

Comment: @Joe Unless I am missing something big, and making complete fool of myself, the above algorithm is wrong. To see why use this test case: `secret_code = ["a", "a", "c", "a", "b", "b", "a"]`, and `guess = ["c", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "c"]`. The output should be: `>>> [1, 1, 0, 0, 0]`

Comment: @blackened You are correct, I didn't come across any test cases that done that, my bad.

Comment: @MathiasEttinger - you are correct, sorry...I shortened the names in my test version and forgot to change them all back when I pasted the code here

Comment: @blackened - ok, I agree, this does not work in all cases...interesting problem to do this efficiently.

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't count as functional programming (which isn't really Python's way), but if I were to code this in Haskell, for example, I would do something like this:

```
def evaluate_key(secret_code, key, position):
    # Will return a None value in case of a "miss", as per your plan.
    if key == secret_code[position]:
        return 1
    elif key in secret_code:
        return 0

def evaluate_guess(secret_code, guess, secret_code_length=4):
    return sorted(
        filter(None.__ne__, # Filter out None values. See https://docs.python.org/3.5/reference/datamodel.html#object.__ne__
            [evaluate_key(secret_code, g, p) 
            for (g, p) in zip(guess, list(range(secret_code_length)))]
        ),
        reverse=True
    )
```

The plan would be to [`zipWith`](http://zvon.org/other/haskell/Outputprelude/zipWith_f.html) the `guess` list and a list of positions (`[0, 1, 2..`]) with the function `evaluate_key` and then sort it.